# Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check : asp-net core

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, http-headers

I know this is a famous error but I'm unable to fix it after trying various solutions.

The request I'm sending is through Angular 2 app. Here's the code for the client request:

```
async registerAdmin(admin: SystemAdminRegistrationViewModel) {

    let response = await this.http.post(this.Account_API_URL + 'accounts/createaccount', admin).toPromise();
    return response;
}
```

I'm using asp.net core 2 web api project for the API. In my Startup.cs class, I have this:

```
    services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", build =>
            {
                build.AllowAnyOrigin()
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowAnyHeader();
            }));



            app.UseCors("MyPolicy");
```

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention that the request works fine when I run the API locally however the error shows up for the request to remote server which is hosted by Azure.

Answer (score 0):

IF you are using Angular 6, you can configure proxy.conf which will act as proxy for your backend API URL. For more information, refer this documentation link https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md